# vs code not running new projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded VS Code on my MacbookAir so i am very new to this. Decided to play around with it and try to create new projects using c# (Ive downloaded all of the needed extensions, .NET, C#, C# Dev Kit, IntelliCode for C#). Each time I open or create a new project, these errors pop up:

[Info  - 10:27:02 PM] [Program] Language server initialized
[Error - 10:27:02 PM] Request textDocument/diagnostic failed.
Message: Unsupported extension '' and LSP language id ''
Code: -32000
[object Object]
[Error - 10:27:02 PM] Document pull failed for text document untitled:Untitled-1
Message: Unsupported extension '' and LSP language id ''
Code: -32000
[object Object]
[Error - 10:27:02 PM] Request textDocument/codeAction failed.
Message: Unsupported extension '' and LSP language id ''
Code: -32000
[object Object]
[Error - 10:27:02 PM] Request textDocument/inlayHint failed.
Message: Unsupported extension '' and LSP language id ''
Code: -32000
[object Object]

if any of you can help me that would be greatly appreciated!

i tried reinstalling vs code and installing it back again. creating new files, folders, etc.

Comment: Does your CLI recognize the `dotnet` command?

Comment: @Brent Yes, it does.